# Chrome version issue affect on react js render

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

On chrome version 71 image not display proper(means image cut), but in google chrome 77 version image display proper using react js

On chrome version less than 77 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwJxo.png

on chrome version 77 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xawnc.png

Comment: Please share the code snippet / UI screenshot

Comment: I edited my question.Check it.